# Python tkinter - Compilation is successful but program runs incorrectly when compiled as an Exe

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

So I created a sort of calculator using tkinter and have made it so that a quick setup creates a save.dat file in the AppData directory and this works as a python script, however when compiled using the line:
`pyinstaller --onefile -w file.py`
it does not work. The `exe` runs the setup process just fine, but it seems, after some testing, when it reaches the end of the if statement, if save.dat already exists (a dialog box appears and there's a do not show again tick box and an OK button), it does not wait for a response and shuts down. I get a glimpse of it as a background process when I check taskmanager, but no window ever appears. I don't understand what the issue is so I could use some help. Here is a snip of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import pickle
import os.path
import sys

def saving():
    messagebox.showinfo("Setting Up", "Setup will now begin")
    path = os.path.expanduser("~/AppData/Local")
    os.chdir(path)
    os.makedirs("hydrocalc")
    loc = os.path.expanduser("~/AppData/Local/hydrocalc/save.dat")
    new = "0"
    pickle.dump(new, open(loc, "wb"))
    
popup = Tk()
popup.withdraw()
loc = os.path.expanduser("~/AppData/Local/hydrocalc/save.dat")
if (os.path.exists(loc)):
    i = pickle.load(open(loc, "rb"))
    # then a few variables referring to the calculator
   def world():
       #the functions referring to the calculator
      if (i == "0"):
        popup.deiconify()
        popup["bg"] = "#f0f0f0"
        popup.title("INSTRUCTIONS")
        labelpu = Label(popup, bg="white", text= #instructions on usage, justify="left").grid()
        popup.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        var = StringVar()
        check = Checkbutton(popup, text="Don't Show Again", variable=var, onvalue="1", offvalue="0", 
        bg="#f0f0f0")
        check.deselect()
        check.grid()
        lbl = Label(popup, text=var.get())

        def btnOkay():
            global i
            lbl = Label(popup, text=var.get())
            if (var.get() == "0"):
                popup.withdraw()
                i = "1"
                calc.deiconify()
                world()
            
            elif (var.get() == "1"):
                
                info = open(loc, 'w+')
                new = "1"
                pickle.dump(new, open(loc, "wb"))
                popup.withdraw()
                calc.deiconify()
                i = "1"
                world()
        popup.deiconify()
        btnOK = Button(popup, text="OK", bg="#f0f0f0", justify="center", width=20, 
        command=lambda:btnOkay()).grid()
    elif (i == "1"):
        calc.deiconify()
        world()
else:
    saving()
    messagebox.showinfo("Setup Complete", "Setup is now complete. Please restart the program to 
    continue.")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Try `pyinstaller -F -c file.py` and capture the error on the terminal and update the question with that,

Comment: I tried this and it opens an empty terminal, runs the saving function (after I deleted the file from my previous tests) and then when I run it again, another blank terminal for a few seconds and then it closes. I'm using Windows 10, but I don't think that should be an issue.

Comment: It is closing because of the `else` condition, right? Whats wrong in that.

Comment: i did a test where i put a message box after each line of code to display the line and when it's forced to slow down by that, it shows that after it 'displays' (it must be so fast that the screen doesn't even register it because i've never seen it without the message boxes) the button (btnOK) it just shuts down. the else statement is running perfectly fine, it's just that it refuses to let me click the button

Comment: Try replacing `sys.exit()` with `popup.destroy()` ?

Comment: That didn't work, nor did removing the line entirely. I ran a test where I printed "hello world" after btnOK and the text in the console showed up briefly but no popup box. The issue seems to lie with the fact that it's either prematurely withdrawing the box or ending the script immediately after it's finished reading through rather than waiting for the button to be clicked to be told what to do next

Comment: Hmm, not sure why.

Comment: Additionally, please edit your question and correct the inundations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a couple of changes to be made, refer to the updated code below

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import pickle
import os.path
import sys

def saving():
    messagebox.showinfo("Setting Up", "Setup will now begin")
    path = os.path.expanduser(appdata)
    os.chdir(path)
    os.makedirs(appdir)
    loc = os.path.expanduser(pref_file)
    new = "0"
    pickle.dump(new, open(loc, "wb"))
    
popup = Tk()
popup.withdraw()

appdata=os.getenv('APPDATA') #modified for my convenience
appdir=os.path.join(appdata,'MyApp')
pref_file=os.path.join(appdir,'pref.pickle')
loc = os.path.expanduser(pref_file)

if (os.path.exists(loc)):

    def world():
        #the functions referring to the calculator
        if (i == "0"):
            popup.deiconify()
            popup["bg"] = "#f0f0f0"
            popup.title("INSTRUCTIONS")
            labelpu = Label(popup, bg="white", text='instructions on usage', justify="left").grid()
            popup.resizable(width=False, height=False)
            var = StringVar()
            check = Checkbutton(popup, text="Don't Show Again", variable=var, onvalue="1", offvalue="0", 
            bg="#f0f0f0")
            check.deselect()
            check.grid()
            lbl = Label(popup, text=var.get())
            btnOK = Button(popup, text="OK", bg="#f0f0f0", justify="center", width=20,command=lambda:btnOkay()).grid()
            def btnOkay():
                global i
                lbl = Label(popup, text=var.get())
                if (var.get() == "0"):
                    popup.withdraw()
                    i = "1"
                    #calc.deiconify()
                    print('deiconified calc') #added for debugging
                
                elif (var.get() == "1"):
                    
                    info = open(loc, 'w+')
                    new = "1"
                    pickle.dump(new, open(loc, "wb"))
                    popup.withdraw()
                    #calc.deiconify()
                    print('deiconified calc') #added for debugging
                    i = "1"
                    world()
                    popup.deiconify()

        elif i == "1":
            #calc.deiconify() commented for debugging
            print('deiconified calc')
            exit() #added for debugging

    i = pickle.load(open(loc, "rb"))
    world()

else:
    saving()
    messagebox.showinfo("Setup Complete", "Setup is now complete. Please restart the program to continue.")
    sys.exit()

popup.mainloop()
```

**NOTES**

- You did not have a `mainloop()` for your program, due to which your window would have never shown up.
- There was no initial call to the `world()` function in the `if` condition.
- Don't call `world()` from the `elif i == "1":` condition, it will lead to infinite recursion.

I still am not completely clear with as to what exactly do you wanted to achieve, let me know if my code met your requirement. Hope it helped.

Comment: The code was slightly altered when i copy and pasted, as I did it in parts, so the above wouldn't be properly functioning, I included it for the lines. However, the issue did stem from the lack of the `mainloop()`, which I overlooked after seeing the code run properly in python. I now have my `exe` fully funcioning, thanks for your help!